# pretty url with .htaccess and QUERY_STRING

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multilingual

i've got some lil problem with my htaccess.
My Links: http://example.com/log/?lang=en
where log - it's a different directory and lang (en or uk or ru)
  But I want some pretty url LIKE:
http://example.com/en/log/

Before I user regex:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA] 

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?)/(.*) $3?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But can't find some  decision for pretty URL

What I want:

By my logic I have to cut lang=en and paste together my host with request_uri
like: host/en/?request_uri
But how to do it?

Comment: Is this .htaccess in `/log/` folder or in `DocumentRoot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(log)/\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA] 

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?)/(.*) $3?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Which URL is causing redirection loop? DO place your full & latest .htaccess in question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry its all working now, thanks a lot. Last question if dirname isn't log?

Comment: number of folders ~ 100

Comment: Change your first rule to: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^/]+)/\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]` to match any dirname there.

Comment: http://example.com/uk/registration/?lang=en                                 How replace old value "uk" by new value "en"?

Comment: Try this: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^/]+/(.*?)\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]` and in next line: `RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=302,L]`

Comment: with this isn't correct work RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^/]+/(.*?)\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC] and in next line: RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=302,L]   all pages redirect on sitename.com/en/ but right path is sitename.com/en/dir/ or sitename.com/en/dir99/    sitename.com/?lang=en not working 2oo. Sorry can u help me again))

Comment: Actually it is getting difficult to understand all the requirements with these comments. But try changing it to: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^/]+/(.+?)\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]`

Comment: If it doesn't work or you want more help then I request you to create a new question listing all the scenarios and I will attend it.

Comment: Thank you, when I'm ready will create a new question. Thank you very much for your help.:)))))))